# unable to create and event handler for workbook/sheet event in a Addd-in

Tags: events, vsto

Im I'm using VS2008 Addin and im trying to write and event handler for a workbook inside the addin but unfortuantly it isn't getting fired can you help

public partial class ThisAddIn
    {

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      FinalWorkbook = ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add(missing);
      FinalWorkbook.SheetActivate +=
            new Excel.WorkbookEvents_SheetActivateEventHandler(
            FinalWorkbook_ActivateSheet);

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show("The addin has shutdown");
    }

    public void FinalWorkbook_ActivateSheet(object odjSheet)
    {
        sheet.BeforeRightClick += Worksheet_BeforeRightClick;
        MessageBox.Show(sheet.Name + " Activated2");

    }

    void Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(Excel.Range Target, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Right-clicking in this sheet" +
            " is not allowed.");

     }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

SheetActivate is only fired when you switch between sheets in the workbook, i.e. you click on Sheet2, then Sheet1 and so on.
If you Alt-Tab to a different application and come back to Excel, SheetActivate won't be fired.

You should look at Application.WorkbookActivate, Workbook.Activate or another event.